# Formatted hd disk wrong. Can’t restor time machine or install new OS. MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, restore

I was trying to restore a time machine backup but then messed everything up as I had erased the wrong disks and was just being a downright idiot for erasing drives. Now I can’t install a fresh OS or restore time machine. Is there any way I can reformat the drives in disk utility to be about to reinstall a new OS? Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click "Partition?"

Answer (score 1):

From your third picture, that's the drive you need to format.

Click the drive name, as you have in that image, then click Erase [top centre] & supply a name. The rest will automatically be set to the correct parameters - Mac OS Extended (Journaled) & GUID Partition Map.

Apple Partition Map is a very old format type, for 68k & PowerPC Macs, not in general use any more.

On installing Sierra the system will likely change that Mac OS Extended (HFS+) format to APFS, but that will be automatic & need not concern you at this juncture.

Comment: It worked! Was able to restore from time machine! Thank you so much!!!!